# device is not listed in adb after setting value of sys.usb.config

Tags: android

I have connected my device to PC via USB for ADB and and UART for minicom. After boot up when I connect my device to pc via USB it is listed in **adb devices**

I have used the this command **getprop | grep usb** in **adb shell** to check the value of **sys.usb.config**
**OUTPUT**
**[init.svc.qcom-usb-sh]: [stopped]**
**[persist.data.df.dev_name]: [rmnet_usb0]**
**[persist.sys.usb.config]: [adb]**
**[persist.sys.usb.config.extra]: [none]**
**[sys.usb.config]: [adb]**
**[sys.usb.configfs]: [0]**
**[sys.usb.ffs.ready]: [1]**
**[sys.usb.state]: [adb]**

But when I set the value to **adb shell setprop sys.usb.config diag,adb,video** then my device is not listed in **adb devices**

**dmesg**:- adb shell setprop sys.usb.config diag,adb,video
**[  500.136525] android_usb gadget: uvc_function_bind**

I have used the this command **getprop | grep usb** in **minicom** to check the value of **sys.usb.config**

**OUTPUT**
**[init.svc.qcom-usb-sh]: [stopped]**
**[persist.data.df.dev_name]: [rmnet_usb0]**
**[persist.sys.usb.config]: [adb]**
**[persist.sys.usb.config.extra]: [none]**
**[sys.usb.config]: [diag,adb,video]**
**[sys.usb.configfs]: [0]**
**[sys.usb.ffs.ready]: [1]**
**[sys.usb.state]: [diag,adb,video]**

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux, when you change the USB state, often times the device will report a different idProduct. You can check by typing "lsusb" on the command line.

For one of my devices, I get (among others)

Bus 001 Device 028: ID 18d1:4337 Google Inc.

You'll need to add a corresponding rule to your /etc/udev/rules.d/[rules file]. In my case, I would add:

SUBSYSTEM=="usb" ATTR{idVendor}="18d1" ATTR{idProduct}=="4337", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"

Your group may be different, depending on if you have plugdev or not.

Comment: When you turn on or off ADB the USB DEVICE ID does change.

Comment: That is incorrect. If you turn off ADB, the device will not enumerate at all. That's because it stops running the adbd daemon. The only time it should change ID is if you change the ADB connection type on device (ie: PTP, MTP, etc)

Comment: I misspoke. The USB Product ID is not the ADB device ID identifier. USB Vendor and Product ID are used to identify the device when it is connected to the host. On Android toggling the developer mode changes the USB Product ID from 0x4ee1 (debug off) to 0x4ee7 (debug on). This is the cause of the problem on the host side. The host doesn't recognize the same physical device with different USB product id as the same device.

Answer (score 1):

The `adb` parameter must be the last, In your case, change from:

```
adb shell setprop sys.usb.config diag,adb,video
```

To:

```
adb shell setprop sys.usb.config diag,video,adb
```